# Create A Generic Class For Response In Rest API

Tags: rest, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I want **Filter** functionality in server Side (Spring Data JPA).
Which is going to use in UI-Grid (AngularJs)

I Have a class **Product**,**Vendor**, etc I want to search byId,ByProductName,ByProductCode,..etc. For All Class.

I Want To create a Generic Class For This which will take Modal className, Column Name, Value, etc.

How I will Create this Generic Class And how to implement the filtering for my Rest Api.

Please Give some Idea about this.

Comment: It sounds like spring-data-rest is a good fit for this job.

Comment: Please, give some idea how to implement this.

Comment: Example guides of [spring-data-reset](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-rest/)

Answer (score 0):

It won't be as generic as you would like to, but you can achieve this kind of result quite easily using QueryBeExmaple - https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#query-by-example